# MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others); When have errors in Validate (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, validate-request

I have 2 routes:

```
Route::post('/post_2', 'TestController@post_2')
    ->name('post_2');
Route::post('/result', 'TestController@result')
    ->name('result');
```

and TestController as below.

```
public function post_2(){
    return view('post_2View');
}
public function result(\App\Http\Requests\Post_2Request $request){
    return "Successful";
}
```

Post_2View

```
<form action="{{route('result')}}" method="post">
           {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="text" name="checkValidate">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

The last is Request to validate checkValidate input in Post_2View

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'checkValidate'=>'required'
    ];
}
public function messages() {
    return [
        'checkValidate.required'=>"This field is required"
    ];
}
```

When I have data in checkValidate input, everything work fine, but when the Request file return errors, I see the error in my browser

```
**
 * Throw a method not allowed HTTP exception.
 *
 * @param  array  $others
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 */
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

Please tell me, how can I solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: do yourself a favor and return a redirect from your `result` route to avoid any confusion on what method was used to display the current page.

Comment: Where you using `post('/post_2'` I mean when you post data to `/post_2` ?

Comment: This is code I use to call post_2. `<form action="{{route('post_2')}}" method="POST">
               {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>`

Answer (score 0):

As you are not sending any data to `/post_2` use `get` verb instead `post` request

```
  Route::get('/post_2', 'TestController@post_2')
->name('post_2');
```

Or you can use both

```
  Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/post_2', 'TestController@post_2')
->name('post_2');
```

Because when you come back after validation it is get request

Comment: I still have a problem there, When I try to do it in my project something happend. `This page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` @user2486

Comment: What you have changed and in which route you are getting this error?

Comment: When I changed in the example I posted here, It worked fine. But in my real project, the errors happend.

Comment: So definitely there some route related to this route `post_2` or any route which recursively calling in your project, find and check this ?

Comment: This is my route in real project. 
       `Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/questionExcel/add', 'admin\part_3\edit_part_3_test_adminController@add_questionExcel')
                ->name('part_3.add.questionExcel');
        
        Route::post('/questionExcelConfirm/add', 'admin\part_3\edit_part_3_test_adminController@add_questionExcelConfirm')
                ->name('part_3.add.questionExcelConfirm');`
I read a Excel file and I show it to check before save it in database.
If you need more code, I will sent you. 
Thank @user2486

Comment: With the example I posted, if I do think you suggest to me, It works fine, but It just happen in my real project.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the reason why this exception happened, but i found a solution if validation failed don't return `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

```
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'name' => 'required'
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json(['message'=>'Name field is required'],422);
            }
```